# Best Way to Add N times Null values to an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am fetching data from Google Sheets using its [API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php).

When I fetch data from Excel Sheet, if the latest elements are empty, arrays size will change according to it. I want it to be fixed; for instance

```
A | B | C | D
-------------
1 | 2 | 3 | 4
1 |   |   | 4
1 | 2 |   |
```

Expected result:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
[1] => Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 4
)
[2] => Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
)
```

Actual result is same for `[0]` and `[1]` but for `[2]` its like below;

```
[2] => Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

So I would like to add **N times empty array values to** the missing ones.

What I tried is `array_fill()` but it only works when I create another array, when I tried to accomplish with `array_push()` I didn't feel like its the optimal solution since I had to use loop-in-loop also here is the solution i tried with `array_fill()`;

NOTE that original array size is much bigger (72).

```
if(count($row) < 3){
$row .= array_fill($row, (3-count($row)), '');
}
```

What is the best method to insert empty array values N times to an array?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create template of the proper length with default values and add them:

```
$row += array_fill(0, 72, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `for` starting from your array length and going to the desired length. filling the array with null along the way.

```
$array = [1,2,3];
$desiredLength = 6;
for($i = count($array); $i < $desiredLength; $i++) {
    $array[$i] = NULL;
}

var_dump($array) // [1,2,3,NULL,NULL,NULL]
```

Note that this solution will only add values to the end of the array.

Comment: Hi @Nicolas, thanks a lot, this solution also works and almost same with my loop solution, but my aim was to avoid extra loop and changed my solution to just as AbraCadaver stated above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Keep in mind that `array_fill` still uses a loop inside.

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought a straight forward use of [`array_pad()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php)

```
$row = array_pad( $row, 72, null );
```